# How do I achieve equal height divs (positioned side by side) with HTML / CSS ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I have two divs inside of a container. One on the left, one on the right, side by side. How am I able to make each one be of equal height, even though they have different content.

For example, the right div has a lot of content, and is double the height of the left div, how do I make the left div stretch to the same height of the right div?

Is there some JavaScript (jQuery) code to accomplish this?

Comment: Once upon a time, tables were used for that.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715360/html-css-set-div-to-height-of-sibling

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You *could* use jQuery, but there are better ways to do this.

This sort of question comes up a lot and there are generally 3 answers...

#### [1. Use CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail)

This is the 'best' way to do it, as it is the most semantically pure approach (without resorting to JS, which has its own problems). The best way is to use the `display: table-cell` and related values. You could also try using [the faux background technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) (which you can do with CSS3 gradients).

#### [2. Use Tables](http://www.sadtrombone.com/)

This seems to work great, but at the expense of having an unsemantic layout. You'll also cause a stir with purists. I have all but avoided using tables, and you should too.

#### [3. Use jQuery / JavaScript](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)

This benefits in having the most semantic markup, except with JS disabled, you will not get the effect you desire.

Comment: alternative to #2: `display:table`. I have noticed a problem with tables, however, that they don't tranition properly. So, CSS3 + tables = no-no

Comment: The second link is dead

Comment: @alex Using flexbox might be another solution too. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253122/make-variable-number-of-divs-positioned-side-by-side-of-equal-height-with-html-c

Comment: This answer is a bit like when someone asks you "How do you find the circumference of a circle" and the response is "using maths".

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to do it with pure CSS, however, as you'll notice in the example (which works in IE 7 and Firefox), borders can be difficult - but they aren't impossible, so it all depends what you want to do.  This example assumes a rather common CSS structure of body > wrapper > content container > column 1 and column 2.

The key is the bottom margin and its canceling padding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Equal Height Columns</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#wrapper { margin: 10px auto; width: 600px; }
#wrapper #main_container { width: 590px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px; background: #CCC; overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 10px solid #CCC; }
#wrapper #main_container div { float: left; width: 263px; background: #999; padding: 10px; margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; margin-bottom: -1000px; padding-bottom: 1000px; }
#wrapper #main_container #right_column { background: #FFF; }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main_container">
        <div id="left_column">
            <p>I have two divs inside of a container. One on the left, one on the right, side by side. How am I able to make each one be of equal height, even though they have different content.</p>
        </div><!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
        <div id="right_column">
          <p>I have two divs inside of a container. One on the left, one on the right, side by side. How am I able to make each one be of equal height, even though they have different content.</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>For example, the right div has a lot of content, and is double the height of the left div, how do I make the left div stretch to the same height of the right div?</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Is there some JavaScript (jQuery) code to accomplish this?</p>
        </div><!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
    </div><!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
</div><!-- WRAPPER -->
</body>
</html>
```

**This is what it looks like:**

[image]

Comment: A very interesting solution! Sadly it won't work if you change #wrapper #main_container div{width: 263px  - > 50% }

Answer (score 4):

you can get it working with js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var height = Math.max($("#left").height(), $("#right").height());
        $("#left").height(height);
        $("#right").height(height);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: wow really like this one Andi, would be even better if it refreshed when browser width is changed. When resizing it the height keeps the same.

Comment: @Andi P. Trix hello! this works fine, but won't change automatically if I attempt to resize the screen, I have to refresh to see results. Some way to do it dynamically? thanks in advance pal!

Answer (score 3):

I've seen many attempts to do this, though none met my OCD needs. You might need to dedicate a second to get your head around this, though it is better than using JavaScript.

Known downsides:

- Does not support multiple element rows in case of a container with dynamic width.
- Does not work in IE6.

The base:

[image: base layout]

- **red** is (auxiliary) container that you would use to set margin to the content.
- **green** is `position: relative; overflow: hidden` and (optionally, if you want columns to be centered) `text-align: center; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;`
- **blue** `display: block; float: left;` or (optionally, if you want columns to be centered) `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`

So far nothing out of ordinary. Whatever content that **blue** element has, you need to add an absolutely positioned element (**yellow**; note that the `z-index` of this element must be lower than the actual *content* of the blue box) with this element and set `top: 0; bottom: 0;` (don't set left or right position).

[image: base with absolute]

All your elements now have equal height. For most of the layouts, this is already sufficient. My scenario required to have dynamic content followed by a static content, where static content must be on the same line.

[image]

To achieve this, you need to add `padding-bottom` (**dark green**) eq to the fixed height content to the **blue** elements.

[image]

Then within the **yellow** elements create another absolutely positioned (`left: 0; bottom: 0;`) element (**dark blue**).

[image]

Supposedly, if these boxes (**yellow**) had to be active hyperlinks and you had any style that you wanted to apply to the original blue boxes, you'd use adjacent sibling selector:

```
yellow:hover + blue {}
```

Here is a the code and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ6Qh/):

HTML:

```
<div id="products">
    <ul>
        <li class="product a">
            <a href="">
                <p class="name">Ordinary product description.</p>
                <div class="icon-product"></div>
            </a>
            <p class="name">Ordinary product description.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="product b">
            <a href="">
                <p class="name">That lenghty product description or whatever else that does not allow you have fixed height for these elements.</p>
                <div class="icon-product"></div>
            </a>
            <p class="name">That lenghty product description or whatever else that does not allow you have fixed height for these elements.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="product c">
            <a href="">
                <p class="name">Another ordinary product description.</p>
                <div class="icon-product"></div>
            </a>
            <p class="name">Another ordinary product description.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS/LESS:

```
#products { 
    ul { position: relative; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;  padding: 0; margin: 0;
        li { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 130px; padding: 0 0 130px 0; margin: 0; }
    }

    li {
        a { display: block; position: absolute; width: 130px; background: rgba(255,0,0,.5); z-index: 3; top: 0; bottom: 0;
            .icon-product { background: #ccc; width: 90px; height: 90px; position: absolute; left: 20px; bottom: 20px; }
            .name { opacity: 1; }
        }

        .name { position: relative; margin: 20px 10px 0; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; opacity: 0; }

        a:hover {
            background: #ddd; text-decoration: none;

            .icon-product { background: #333; }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that the demo is using a workaround that involves data-duplication to fix `z-index`. Alternatively, you could use `pointer-events: none` and whatever solution for IE.

Answer (score 1):

here is very simple solution with a short css display:table

```
<div id="main" class="_dt-no-rows">
  <div id="aside" contenteditable="true">
    Aside
    <br>
    Here's the aside content
  </div>
  <div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    Content
    <br>
    geht's pellentesque wurscht elementum semper tellus s'guelt Pfourtz !. gal hopla
    <br>
    TIP : Just clic on this block to add/remove some text
  </div>
</div>
```

here is css

```
#main {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
#aside, #content {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}
#aside {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
  width: 250px;
}
#content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E69B00;
}
```

its look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't do a ton of jQuery, but in the CSS/Javascript world I would just use the object model and write a statement as follows:

```
if(leftDiv.style.height > rightDive.style.height)
   rightDiv.style.height = leftDiv.style.height;
else
   leftDiv.style.height = rightDiv.style.height)
```

Comment: You could use `Math.max()` here, and set them both to it. Maybe more elegant.

Comment: was good enough in 2009 when it was written, but with responsive layouts its get much more complicated.

Comment: You seriously downvoted an answer 7 years later because the technology is different?

Comment: I needed to find a non jquery method to do this. This thread came up on a google search. It was like 2 in the morning, my bad for the downvote offense.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a jQuery plugin called equalHeights that I've used with some success.

I'm not sure if the one I'm using is the one from the filament group mentioned above, or if it's [this one that was the first google result](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/)... Either way a jquery plugin is probably the easiest, most flexible way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in jquery document ready function. Considering there are two divs having ids "left" and "right."

```
var heightR = $("#right").height();
var heightL = $("#left").height();

if(heightL > heightR){
    $("#right").css({ height: heightL});
} else {
    $("#left").css({ height: heightR});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although many disagree with using javascript for this type of thing, here is a method that I used to acheive this using javascript alone:

```
var rightHeight = document.getElementById('right').clientHeight;
var leftHeight = document.getElementById('left').clientHeight;
if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
document.getElementById('right').style.height=leftHeight+'px';
} else {
document.getElementById('left').style.height=rightHeight+'px';
}
```

With "left" and "right" being the id's of the two div tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in plain javascript:

Seems long, but is very uncomplicated!

```
function equalizeHeights(elements){
    //elements as array of elements (obtain like this: [document.getElementById("domElementId"),document.getElementById("anotherDomElementId")]

    var heights = [];
    for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        heights.push(getElementHeight(elements[i],true));
    }

    var maxHeight =  heights[biggestElementIndex(heights)];

    for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        setElementHeight(elements[i],maxHeight,true);
    }
}

function getElementHeight(element, isTotalHeight){
    // isTotalHeight triggers offsetHeight
    //The offsetHeight property is similar to the clientHeight property, but it returns the height including the padding, scrollBar and the border.
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript
    {
        isTotalHeight = typeof isTotalHeight !== 'undefined' ? isTotalHeight : true;
    }

    if (isTotalHeight){
        return  element.offsetHeight;
    }else{
        return element.clientHeight;
    }
}

 function setElementHeight(element,pixelHeight, setAsMinimumHeight){

    //setAsMinimumHeight: is set, we define the minimum height, so it can still become higher if things change...
    {
        setAsMinimumHeight = typeof setAsMinimumHeight !== 'undefined' ? setAsMinimumHeight : false;
    }
    var heightStr = "" + pixelHeight + "px";
    if (setAsMinimumHeight){
        element.style.minHeight = heightStr; // pixels
    }else{
        element.style.height = heightStr; // pixels
    }
}

 function biggestElementIndex(arr){
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array
    var max = arr[0];
    var maxIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            maxIndex = i;
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with initial answer but the JS solution with equal_heights() method does not work in some situations, imagine you have products next to each other. If you were to apply it only to the parent container yes they will be same height but the product name sections might differ if one does not fit to two line, this is where i would suggest using below

https://jsfiddle.net/0hdtLfy5/3/

```
function make_children_same_height(element_parent, child_elements) {
    for (i = 0; i < child_elements.length; i++) {
    var tallest = 0;
    var an_element = child_elements[i];
    $(element_parent).children(an_element).each(function() {
      // using outer height since that includes the border and padding
      if(tallest < $(this).outerHeight() ){
        tallest = $(this).outerHeight();
      }
    });

    tallest = tallest+1; // some weird shit going on with half a pixel or something in FF and IE9, no time to figure out now, sowwy, hence adding 1 px
    $(element_parent).children(an_element).each(function() {
        $(this).css('min-height',tallest+'px');
    });
  }
}
```