# CSS/JavaScript Technique to dynamically force 2 divs to be the size of the larger div

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 divs, a main content section and a sidebar.

What I want to happen is force each div to be the same height as the tallest div

If the Sidebar Content is taller then the Main Content I want to push the Main Content down to match the Sidebar Content's height

```
+--------------------+----------+
|  Main Content      | Sidebar  |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|  END               |          |
| __________________ |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |  END     |
|                    | ________ |
+--------------------+----------+
```

Conversely, if the Main Content is taller then the Sidebar Content I want to push the Sidebar Content down to match the Main Content's height

```
+--------------------+----------+
|  Main Content      | Sidebar  |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |  END     |
|                    | ________ |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|  END               |          |
| __________________ |          |
+--------------------+----------+
```

So it would look like this:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|  Main Content      | Sidebar  |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|                    |          |
|   END              |  END     |
| __________________ | ________ |
+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [equal height columns](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight), which can be accomplished with CSS only, without any javascript.

There are other ways to do this, including jQuery.  See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056212/how-do-i-achieve-equal-height-divs-with-html-css) for more information.

Comment: i need it to be more dynamic, because I don't know the size of the tallest div.

Comment: The CSS solution *is* dynamic, the two columns will always be the same  height.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use jQuery or another framework to extrapolate the height of your tallest div and then set the height to the others accordingly?

```
if($('#mainContent').height() >= $('#subContent').height()) {
    $('#subContent').height($('#mainContent').height());
}
else
{
    $('#mainContent').height($('#subContent').height());
}
```