# Equal height on each popups div

Tags: jquery

How to put equal heigts on each multiple divs?

```
<div class="brands">
    <div class="left" style="height:50px;">different height 1 same group</div>
    <div class="right" style="height:50px;">different height 2 same group</div>
</div>
 <div class="brands">
    <div class="left" style="height:150px;">different height 3 same group</div>
    <div class="right" style="height:150px;">different height 4 same group</div>
</div>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Mm don't understand the question, what has it to do with jQuery? You looking for: `.brands div { height: 10px; }`?

Comment: Need more information on what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them all the same:

```
$('div.brands').children('div').css('height', '100px');
```

Or, if different ones need different heights:

```
$('div.brands').eq(0).children('div').css('height', '50px');
$('div.brands').eq(1).children('div').css('height', '150px');
```

To set child divs to the height of the tallest child div in a given brands div:

```
var leftHeight = 0;
var rightHeight = 0;
$('div.brands').each(function() {
    leftHeight = $(this).children('div.left').height();
    rightHeight = $(this).children('div.right').height();
    if(leftHeight > rightHeight) {
        $(this).children('div.right').css('height', leftHeight + 'px');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children('div.left').css('height', rightHeight + 'px');
    }        
});
```

Comment: But how to set height on automaticaly? style attr is for example, for group spliting, for better understanding my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking...?

Comment: Brands divs ar multiple, for example 50 divs.

Comment: For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688250/setting-equal-heights-for-divs-with-jquery

Comment: So you want to set all the divs to the height of the tallest div?  Because that's what that question asks and answers, as far as I can tell

Comment: Updated it with code to make all divs the height of the tallest div

Comment: Fixed it - changes height of child divs of div.brands divs

Comment: And how to set only children divs? Here is image example of problem: http://www.styleweb.lv/height_fix.jpg

Comment: This will only select and change child divs - it won't select div.brands divs

Comment: And how to set on child divs, like on picture example? This solution for all divs dont fix the problem.

Comment: I think I finally have what you wanted - to set the left and right divs in a given brands div to the same height

Comment: Almost right, but code example don't work. Console shows nothing.

Comment: Try it now - fixed the CSS setting function

Comment: Many thanks. All work good. Only need fixing padding height issue with css.

Comment: Here is update "if(leftHeight > rightHeight) {
   $(this).children('div.brands_stats').css('height', leftHeight + 'px');
   $(this).children('div.brands_info').css('height', leftHeight + 'px');
  }
  else {
   $(this).children('div.brands_info').css('height', rightHeight + 'px');
   $(this).children('div.brands_stats').css('height', rightHeight + 'px');
  }     "