# Scale div with background image to remaining height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap page that looks like this:

```
<nav> ... </nav> <!-- height not fixed -->
<div class="container-fluid eye-catcher">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 image"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the end, it should look like this:
[image]

The code for the image I have is this, which works fine...

```
.image {
  background-image: url("image.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}
```

...but how can I let the row filling up (only) the remaining space (no scrollbar should be visible then)

Comment: add CSS `overflow: hidden` to the element which size shouldn't be disrespected. Even if it is `body`

Comment: @warkentien2 that's something I'd really like to avoid.

Comment: So you will want that the row have the same height as the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some `Flexbox` with `media queries`. Full code [`HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/549/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
nav {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.image {
  background: lightblue;
}
.left {
  background: lightgreen;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .eye-catcher {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to have the two columns the same height? this requires javascript or you can use display: table-cell to manage this, look it up. Via javascript it is by using [match-height plugin](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) or by creating a little custom script: [http://stack/setting-equal-heights-for-divs-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688250/setting-equal-heights-for-divs-with-jquery)