# Adjust Divs height related to another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four divs side by side. I'd like the height of them to be the same, and stay the same if one of them resizes. means,  if one grows because text is placed into it, the other one should grow to match the height.

Here is my `:`[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94uvouzw/1/)

**Please resize the width of answer**

Thank you.

Comment: Well, there are 2 side-by-side in 2 rows, so do you mean they all 4 should have same height? ... Or all 4 should be on the same row?

Comment: @LGSon,  In Smaller Screen that's not a problem. But larger screen it split into 2 lines. so, that time the problem happens.

Comment: Okay, to make elements on different rows the same height you need a script...elements on the same row can keep same height using CSS, which is normally more important, so they all vertical align properly

Comment: @LGSon All 4 they have same height. Please help me to do this. I am not familiar with scripts.

Comment: I updated your tags to include script, to attract users with more experience when it comes to script based solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688250/setting-equal-heights-for-divs-with-jquery

Comment: take a look on this article http://vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/94uvouzw/6/show/ use flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your solution you should use display:flex

```
jsfiddle.net/94uvouzw/7/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height;
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".test").each(function(){
        height = $(this).height();
        if(height > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = height;
        }
    });
    $(".test").css("height",maxHeight);
});
```

By using jQuery

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3w8j5q2/)

Comment: You can always add [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to your jquery answer to make it more clear and acceptable.