# JQuery, height of div wrongly recognized due to images content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs (DivLeft, DivRight) next to each other, they are wrapped in DivHolder. DivRight contains another divs and thus expand in height. I want the DivLeft to have min-height same as DivRight has.

HTML looks more or less like this:

```
<div class="DivHolder">
   <div class="DivLeft"></div>
   <div class="DivRight">
      <div class="add1"></div>
      <div class="add2"><img ...></div>
      <div class="add3"><img ...></div>
      ....
   </div>
</div>
```

Tried this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($(".DivHolder").length > 0) {

         $(".DivLeft").css("minHeight", $(".DivRight").height());
    }
}
```

and it append some height to DivLeft, but a wrong one. I checked the height of DivRight, and it is 720px, but the min-height DivLeft gain is 241px. No div that is contained in DivRight is of this height. It seems to be a "random" value. Anyone see the problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have found the root of the problem is that some of the divs that are included in **DivRight contains images.** These images are not loaded when I call my function and thus DivRight appears to be shorter.

I changed $(document).ready(function () for $(window).load(function() {, but now I can see the **DivLeft jumps** in height (at first its original height is set and after the images are loaded, it extends). That looks bad. Any tips how to improve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619813/jquery-equal-height-divs ? If you mean equal height ?

Comment: The problem is caused by images included in divs in DivRight. Please, read EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem usign this:

```
 if ($(".DivHolder").length > 0) {
    $(".DivRight").find("img").load(function (){
       $(".DivLeft").css("minHeight", $(".DivRight").height());
    });
 }
```

No jumping can be seen, works nicely!

Comment: I have just found, that Chrome doesn't care whether the image is loaded, not even if it is in $(document).ready(function (). Thus after clicking to a link, where this function is loaded, it doesn't work. I solved it by setting images the height firstly.

Answer (score 2):

In your case...

```
$('.DivLeft').css('min-height', $('.DivRight').height());
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/tE6ER/

---

Or something like.. (Equal Height)

```
$('.DivLeft, .DivRight').height(
        Math.max(
            $('.DivLeft').height(),
            $('.DivRight').height()
        )
);
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/2WPwu/