# div height based on another div height

Tags: css

I have 3 columns theme and I would like to have all columns same height. Height of column left and right are fixed and should be the same as dynamic height column middle.

layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar-left">Sidebar left</div>   
            <div id="sidebar-middle">BIG SIDEBAR MIDDLE</div>  
            <div id="sidebar-right">Sidebar right</div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

'

CSS code:

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    background:#FFEE33;   
}
#container {         
    min-height:100%;
    background:#FFAA00; 
}           
#sidebar-left,
#sidebar-right{   
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    min-height:100%; 
    background:#FF0000;
}  
#sidebar-middle {  
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    height:2000px;
    background:#444;
}
```

Is this possible to make only in CSS?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715360/html-css-set-div-to-height-of-sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715360/html-css-set-div-to-height-of-sibling)

Answer (score 0):

try adding a clearfix after your columns. This should force the container to size according to its contents. When you float elements they loose their height values - by adding a clear after a list of floated elements they regain this property.

simple -

add to css

```
.clearfix{
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}
```

and html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar-left">Sidebar left</div>   
            <div id="sidebar-middle">BIG SIDEBAR MIDDLE</div>  
            <div id="sidebar-right">Sidebar right</div> 
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You can't set class like this `<div class='clear'></div>`, should be `<div class="clear"></div>`, and change to `<div class="clearfix"></div>` as you are adding style to `clearfix` class, not to `clear`. And will not help anyway :)