# Image and Text One Row Size Issue

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]Here is my html code:

```
I have attached all the images first image is the image where i am getting issue and second one is the image which is correct and third is for mobile display.

<div class="eighth-page" id="eighth-page">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #E44E29;display: inline;">
            <div class="eight-page-content">
               <div class="eighth-page-heading">
                  <h3>PX Booth</span></h3>
                  <h5>PX Booth Hire</span></h5>
                  <!-- line height -->
                  <h5>PX Booth Hire</span></h5>
                  <!-- line height -->
               </div>
               <div class="eight-page-text">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                  <p>
                     It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
               </div>
               <div class="eighth-page-content-btn">
                  <a href="#"><span class="btn-learn">Learn</span><span class="btn-more">More</span></a> 
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="eighth-page-img">
               <img src="img/5.jpg" class="img-responsive eighth-img">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

/*----------------------
Eighth Page - colored 
----------------------*/

```
.eight-page-content {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 80%;
}
.eighth-page-heading h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.eighth-page-heading h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9dff00;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.eight-page-text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.eight-page-text p {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.eighth-page-content-btn {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.eighth-page-content-btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-learn {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #9dff00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
}
.btn-more {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #f2f0f4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.bg-color
{
  background-color: #E44E29;
  display: inline;
}
```

### /*

### Media query for content of colored box

*/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
  .eight-page-content {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 80%;
}
.eighth-page-heading h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.eighth-page-heading h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9dff00;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.eight-page-text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.eight-page-text p {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.eighth-page-content-btn {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.eighth-page-content-btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-learn {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #9dff00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
}
.btn-more {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #f2f0f4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.bg-color
{
  background-color: #E44E29;
  display: inline;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
  .eight-page-content {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 80%;
}
.eighth-page-heading h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.eighth-page-heading h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9dff00;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.eight-page-text {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.eight-page-text p {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.eighth-page-content-btn {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
}
.eighth-page-content-btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-learn {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #9dff00;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
}
.btn-more {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #f2f0f4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.bg-color
{
  background-color: #E44E29 !important;
  display: inline;
}
}
/*----------------------------------
Media Query for img of eighth page
----------------------------------*/
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .eighth-page-img img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .eighth-page-img img {
        max-width: 100vh;
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .eighth-page-img img {
        max-width: 100vh;
        height: 480px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .eighth-page-img img {
        max-width: 100vh;
        height: 436px;
    }
}
```

[image: PFA image which I want to make and I have already coded it and shared above but when I resize the browser size the image is resized. This is the main issue I am getting in it.]

[![This is the issue I am getting when I resize the browser. I have used max-height: 100vh and max-width:100vh. Either the image get stretched or image get magnified and overflow out of the div.
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHPSX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHPSX.png)

[image: And Now on the mobile background color of text section disappeared and everything is blasted.]

**Please help as I am new to the Front End Technology.I am using bootstrap3 and also tried flexbox but the issue is not resolved. Please help me out and I am using image of size 4000X2670 pixels.**

Comment: Just a quick tip: try to be consistent and not use `eight` and `eighth` interchangeably in your class names. That's just asking for subtle bugs from simple typos that will be very hard to find.

Comment: I will change that in the code and will always keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this:

```
div.eighth-page-img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.eighth-page-img img {
    width:100%; //or height:100% according to your requirement
    position:absolute;
    left:50px; // adjust according to your requirement
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working. Please check it and try with resizing the browser size. Please share the code also which runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the text element doesnt have the same proportion as the image. Therefore the image will get stretched if you force it to be the same height as the text element. On the other hand, if you adjust the image's width to the max of the container, you Will experience the White space, as it simply has other proportions.

If you dont want to crop the image at all (or use JavaScript), i think your only choice is to force the text element to have the same proportions as the image (with width approximately being 50% larger than height), and then adjust the font-size/text elements to fit the container.

Note: this should maybe have been a comment, but I dont have the reputation to make comment.

---

**EDIT:**
I might have been too vague in my suggestion as resizing the actual image won't fix the issue in all cases. As soon as you resize the window the text will be pushed downwards when decreasing the window width, making the proportions wrong again.

Therefore, my suggestions would be one of the following (only using CSS and not JavaScript):


**Suggestion 1 - make image container `position:absolute` and insert image as a background:**

Show the image as a css `background-image` with the css `background-size: cover` property. This will crop the image when it's larger than the container, but it will fill the entire container.

To achieve this you could add the following (**Important:** remember to delete the `<img>` from the HTML text):

```
.row{
position:relative;
}

.eighth-page-img{
position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
   background-image: url("img/5.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Note the following with this method:

- You can position the image relatively easily with the `background-position` property, enabling you to move the image to show the content of it which you want the user to see (in case that much of the image is hidden due to cropping).
- The better you resize/fit the text elements in the container to the left, to match the proportions of the image, the more of the image you will see (as the proportions will be more alike).
- The advantage of this method is that you can load different images based in media queries to support mobiles, without loading multiple images (making page load faster and more mobile friendly, if you load smallere images to mobile). Although this is also possibly in suggestion 2 if you ude the `srcset` property; however im not sure of the support for this.
- The downside of this method might be the fact that the image isn't an actual DOM-element. This can **possibly** influence your SEO in the sense, that your image simply won't be taken into consideration the same way as using the `<img>` property with an `alt` description.

**Suggestion 2 - Insert the image with the `<img>` property, `position:absolute` it's container and use `z-index` to prevent the image/div from overlapping the text-element to the left.**


This will include your `<img>` in the SEO - the only "problem" about this might be that it takes a bit more "managing" to fit in every case. You'll most likely have to check and adjust the `left` property on different window sizes to make sure that it looks as you want it to.

```
.row{
position:relative;
}

.eighth-page-img{
 overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}

.eighth-page-img img{
  height:100%;
  /* Change the left property to match your needs. */
  left:-30%; 
  position:absolute;
}
```

**Suggestion 3 - show containers as a table (use css `display:table` and `display:table-cell`) which will make the containers the same size.** 

You can see this technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715360/html-css-set-div-to-height-of-sibling).

However using this technique you still have to adjust the image- or text size, such as inserting the image as a background (as in suggestion 1).

Comment: I can change the size of the image and also crop as these are the dummy images. Please tell me how much should be the perfect size or any relevant information so that i can start doing it.

Comment: I am working your Answer only @Chri.s . But I am not getting the perfect solution . Can we share personal Email so that we can resolve this ?

Comment: @HimanshuChawla is the code from your question everything concerning the elements?

Comment: @HimanshuChawla i can't help you any further without all the HTML and CSS you have, and i'm afraid that i'm not gonna share my personal e-mail on a public forum.

Comment: Can you inbox me on stackoverflow only . Actually i am afraid to share my code on the website.