# How can I set the height of an element to the computed height of another one?

Tags: html, css

I have a `form` and an `ul` inside a `flexbox`.

I have set the `height` of `ul` manually. **not what I want tho*

How can I set the height of `ul` to the computed height of `form`?

[image: Edit computed-height]

- Do not use `ref`
- Check `styles.css`

Comment: Please add a [repro] for debugging details. Also what have you tried so far? `height: 100%;`? JS: `innerHeight`/`outerHeight`?

Comment: I've removed items from the list and the list box is the same height as the form box. I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: The default values of the flexible container mean that your children's height will automatically stretch to the height of the tallest child. In the case of the example you have linked above, it's the list which is actually causing the form to increase in height due to the larger amount of content

Comment: @Ken The height of the list and the form exceeds if you add list items back.

Comment: @JacobRiches Exactly. I want to set the height of the list so items can scroll.

Comment: Gotcha, set the height of the section to any height you wish, 100px for this example, and then set height of the ul to height: 100%;. That will do the trick

Comment: @JacobRiches But I don't want to set the height manually. I want the automatic computed height of the `form`.

Comment: @Hamidreza So, you might want to set the height of form to the height of ul. Since they are sibling elements I hope this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715360/html-css-set-div-to-height-of-sibling) might be useful

Comment: Sandbox edited.

Comment: This is how I would do it with vanilla JS but I'm not 100% sure how you would do the same in React as document.query selector doesn't play too nice with the virtual DOM I'm told. https://codepen.io/jriches/pen/YzQzOoG

Could be a good starting place though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does more or less what you want.

I've changed the html, by including an extra div. I've commented the changes to the css.

The basic principle is this: make the height of the `section` depend only on the height of the `form`, by removing the `ul` from the flow, using `position:absolute`. Then set `max-height` for the `ul` to `100%`, which will be 100% of the `section`... which in turn is derived from the height of the contained `form`.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  position:relative; /* position relative means contained items are relative to this */
}

form {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  
}

ul {
  position:absolute; /* position absolute means the size of this block doesn't affect the height of the container */

  max-height:100%; /* 100% of the containing section, which has position:relative */
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <form>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Adobe</li>
        <li>Amazon</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Google</li>
        <li>Microsoft</li>
        <li>Netflix</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What is that extra `div` for?

Comment: The extra `div` does not have `position:absolute`, so it gets positioned relative to the form. Without that, the `ul` block is positioned on top of the form

Answer (score 1):

First, set the section container `position` to `relative`. Then, **to make the form box adjust to the content use `height: fit-content;`**. Finally, for the ul box use `position: absolute;`, `max-height: 100%;` and `overflow: scroll;`.

See example below.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

form {
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: chocolate;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Adobe</li>
      <li>Amazon</li>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Google</li>
      <li>Microsoft</li>
      <li>Netflix</li>
      <li>Adobe</li>
      <li>Amazon</li>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Google</li>
      <li>Microsoft</li>
      <li>Netflix</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is nice, but it introduces a manual setting for the width of the section (200px), which might not be wanted.

Comment: Ignore the comment above. The recent edit introduces a `div` containing the `ul`, and removes the setting of the width, so my comment is out of date.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisLear, I thought the same.