# Properly aligning div elements

Tags: html, css

I've been tinkering with this for an hour now and can't quite get it to work.

Basically I have two div elements I want to align next to each other and I want them to be the same height.  The height of the second element should match the first since the first can have 1-3 lines of text.

See the HTML below and this link for a pic of the current output.

http://i55.tinypic.com/2ajozgw.jpg

Sorry for the inline CSS, plan on taking it out once I get it right.

```
            <div style="width:450px;margin:0px auto;">
                <div style="width:90%;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;border-left:2px solid #606060;border-top:2px solid #606060;border-bottom:2px solid #606060;border-right:1px solid #606060;padding:10px;font-size:0.9em;float:left;">
                    CATEGORY<br />
                    Test
                 </div>
                <div style="width:10%;background-color:#000000;text-align:center;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px;-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;border-top:2px solid #606060;border-bottom:2px solid #606060;border-right:1px solid #606060;padding:10px;float:left;">
                        9
                </div>      
            </div>
```

Comment: There are many questions on SO concerning equal height columns using css, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns

Comment: This question's been asked before, hasn't it? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056212/how-do-i-achieve-equal-height-divs-with-html-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (i removed round corners):

```
<div style="width:400px; position:relative">
    <div style="width:350px; border: solid 1px black">
        CATEGORY<br>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50px;position: absolute; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; background: black;">
    9
    </div>      
</div>
```

This is how it looks like: http://i52.tinypic.com/2zisndt.png

Comment: +1 Nice one, I wonder how the IE compatibility is (I think older versions don´t like `right` and `bottom`).

Comment: This works great, and works in IE7 and up.  Any idea how I can vertically align the second element?  vertical-align:middle doesn't seem to work =(

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution would be to put this into a table that has one row and two cells. The cells get automatically the same height, and you can make the DIV to span the whole cell.

Comment: **NO!!! TABLES ARE BAD!** Tables are *depreciated*! They can't even be used to display tabular data. I'd downvote, but this isn't a bad answer ;)

Comment: @Blender Although I agree that tables shouldn´t be used for layout, they are definitely the right choice for displaying tabular data. **Tables rock for tabular data!** ;-)

Comment: I was going to use a table but they don't play well with rounded corners.

Comment: @Tom Depending on your browser needs, you can resort to `display:table-cell`.

Comment: @Tom Yes, that would work in IE8 and higher, see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html