# How to have elements copy other element's auto height css?

Tags: jquery, css, element

I have a right column on my page that has varying heights, set as height: auto;

I also have a left content section, that I want to mimic the height of my right column.

How can I do this using css, jquery, or some other code?

Comment: I think you're after [this sort of thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056212/how-do-i-achieve-equal-height-divs-with-html-css).

Comment: Cant you just set them to be within the same html table row?

Comment: My apologies, I was answering the question that I saw in the title. You might want to rephrase it a bit more specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('#primary').height();
    $('#sidebar').css('height', x);
});
```

This jQuery snippet will take the height of `#primary` and apply it to `#sidebar`, syncing the height of both elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/pUXCE/4/  <-- working example.

Comment: It works, there was just a type-o in the word "function". Try it again with the proper spelling, should work as intended.