# Smallest number in array and its position

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am trying to achieve is to find smallest number in array and its initial position. Here's an example what it should do:

```
temp = new Array();
temp[0] = 43;
temp[1] = 3;
temp[2] = 23;
```

So in the end I should know number 3 and position 1. I also had a look here: [Obtain smallest value from array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript), but this way does not give me a number position in the array. Any tips, or code snippets are appreciated.

Comment: Oh my god. I just realized that I could use indexOf to find position of the smallest number.

Comment: Ed.T Thanks for mentioning `indexOf`. It helped me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just loop through the array and look for the lowest number:

```
var index = 0;
var value = temp[0];
for (var i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {
  if (temp[i] < value) {
    value = temp[i];
    index = i;
  }
}
```

Now `value` contains the lowest value, and `index` contains the lowest index where there is such a value in the array.

Answer (score 8):

One-liner:

```
alist=[5,6,3,8,2]

idx=alist.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null,alist))
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, explain what the code does.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use `indexOf`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Using the code that you had before, from the other question:

```
temp = new Array();
temp[0] = 43;
temp[1] = 3;
temp[2] = 23;

Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};

var value = temp.min;
var key = temp.indexOf(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the smallest value using `Math.min` and the spread operator:

```
var minimumValue = Math.min(...temp);
```

Then find the index using `indexOf`:

```
var minimumValueIndex = temp.indexOf(minimumValue);
```

I personally prefer the spread operator over `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850912/8573978) of "find max" version of this question. It is simple and good. You can use the index to get the element afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using simple recursion. The output is an object containing the index position of the min number and the min number itself

```js
const findMinIndex = (arr, min, minIndex, i) => {
  if (arr.length === i) return {minIndex, min};
  if (arr[i] < min) {
    min = arr[i]
    minIndex = i;
  }
  return findMinIndex(arr, min, minIndex, ++i)

}

const arr = [5, 5, 22, 11, 6, 7, 9, 22];
const minIndex = findMinIndex(arr, arr[0], 0, 0)
console.log(minIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce, and compare against `Infinity`.

```
let minIndex = -1;
arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (curr < acc) {
        minIndex = index;
        return curr;
    } else {
        return acc;
    }
}, Infinity);
```