# How does .apply(Math, arrayName) work in JS?

Tags: javascript, this

There is [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript) [than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values) [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array) stackoverflow question about how to find the min or max of an array of values in javascript. This is not that question.

I want to know why passing `.apply()` strange things as the `this` argument still works. Despite [a good blog post](http://aaroncrane.co.uk/2008/11/javascript_max_api/) from Aaron Crane on how the Math object's API became what it is, there's still something left unanswered.

Each of the following code snippets work. My question is, how? What exactly is happening with the assignment to `this` that makes each of these work?

The Standard Construction

```
var values = [45, 46, 47]
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, values);
alert(min); //45
```

A Weirder Construction, But Scope can be Tricky...

```
var values = [45, 46, 47]
var min = Math.min.apply(this, values);
alert(min); //45
```

Slightly Weirder

```
var values = [45, 46, 47]
var min = Math.min.apply(global, values);
alert(min); //45
```

Weirder Still, But Maybe Okay b/c Browsers

```
var values = [45, 46, 47]
var min = Math.min.apply(window, values);
alert(min); //45
```

Very Weird

```
var values = [45, 46, 47]
var min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
alert(min); //45
```

Truly Weird

```
var values = [45, 46, 47]
var min = Math.min.apply(undefined, values);
alert(min); //45
```

Comment: `Math.min` doesn't use `this` in any way, so it literally doesn't matter what you pass it, it doesn't care.

Comment: The value passed as the `thisArg` only matters to the `function` if it depends on `this` having a particular value. And, `Math.min()` [doesn't need to reference `this` at all](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.12).

Comment: The first argument to `apply` is the value that should be used as `this` within the function. Since `Math.min` doesn’t _use_ `this` for anything, it logically doesn’t matter one bit what you pass as `this` via the parameter … you might as well pass `"foobar"` or `9/11` as first parameter to `apply` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` don't actually use the `this` argument passed to them, it's just a hack to get them to accept an array of arguments, since the native API only specifies a list of variables. `.apply()` *can* accept arrays of arguments, which is why it is used.

My guess is `Math` is passed in as the `this` argument simply for cleanliness' sake.

Thanks to @Jonathan Lonowski and @Niet the Dark Absol.

Answer (score 4):

When using `.apply()`, the first argument controls what the `this` pointer value will be set to when the function executes.  In many cases, the `this` value is critically important.  In a few cases, the `this` value is simply not used inside the function implementation (often referred to as a static function that does not operate on instance data).  When `this` is not used, it doesn't matter what `this` is set to and therefore it doesn't matter what the first argument to `.apply()` is set to.

So, in your specific case, `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` (and probably all the `Math.xxx()` functions) do not use the `this` pointer at all as they are all basically static functions that don't operate on instance data.  So, it doesn't matter what it's set to and thus you can pass anything you want as the first argument to `Math.min.apply()` and it won't change the result of the function call.

---

I would argue that one should still pass the correct value there which would be `Math` since that's what `this` will be when you do a normal:

```
Math.min(x, y);
```

So, to present the exact same situation to `Math.min()` as the above code when using `.apply()`, you would do it like this:

```
var arr = [x, y];
Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
```

---

IMO, this promotes proper habits and proper thinking about what that first argument is supposed to be because it will matter in other circumstances.

FYI, a similar issue comes up regularly with `$.when.apply($, arr)` in jQuery which also doesn't use the `this` argument in its implementation so one can call it as `$.when.apply(null, arr)` or even `$.when.apply("foo", arr)`.  Personally, I prefer to pass the "technically correct" argument which is the first one.

---

FYI, in modern Javascript (ES2015+), you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in place of `.apply()` for this particular type of operation:

```
const arr = [1,2];
const maxVal = Math.max(...arr);
```

And, the array is unpacked for you automatically into separate arguments by the spread syntax.  And there is no decision on what to pass to that first argument of `.apply()` as you're just making the exact same `Math.max()` function call with no manipulation of anything.

Comment: Added reference to ES2015 spread syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What `apply` does with its first argument, is simply setting the context (`this`) for the function that it is called on.

So lets say, you have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: function () {
        return this.a;
    },
    c: function () {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

If you call `obj.b()`, you will get `1` as returned value, since `this` in this scenario is defined by calling `b` with `obj` in front of it (`this === obj`). To change that, you can use `apply`:

```
obj.b.apply({a:2});
```

This will return 2, because you are now explicitly settings `this` to `{a:2}`.

BUT: if you have a function, that doesn't make use of `this` internally, than it doesn't matter what value `this` has. So you can call:

```
obj.c();
```

or one of these:

```
obj.apply.c(null);
obj.apply.c(undefined);
obj.apply.c("xyz");
```

But you will always get the same result `3`. It is like setting a variable that you never use. No matter what value it is, it doesn't affect the outcome.

So apparently `Math.min` doesn't use `this` and therefore doesn`t break when passing an "invalid" context.

Answer (score 0):

This (so to speak) is a tricky part of JavaScript.

When you have a function, there's a magical variable called `this`. Depending on how you call a function, its context is set differently.

```
function myFunction() {
  return this;
}

var myObject = {
  fn: function() {
    return this;
  }
};

myFunction();  // the global object. `window` in browsers, `global` in Node.js
myFunction.apply(Math);  // Math
myFunction.apply({ hello: "world" });  // { hello: "world" }

myObject.fn();               // myObject
myObject.fn.apply(myObject); // myObject
myObject.fn.apply(Math);     // Math
```

The reason that your examples above work is because `min` doesn't use `this` at all, so you can assign it to whatever you want.