# How to find minimum decimal value in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array with decimal nos such as

```
  var idArray = ["98.40", "111.46", "144.47", "180.48", "217.49", "284.50", "424.51", "571.52", "1887.53", "1960.54", "1972.55", "2118.56", "2167.57", "2467.58", "2480.59", "2488.60", "2662.61", "2671.62", "2767.63", "2982.64", "3168.65", "3263.66", "3295.67", "3369.68", "3579.69", "3592.70", "3600.71", "3605.72", "3620.73", "3646.74", "3852.75", "3857.76", "4031.77", "4489.78", "4975.79"]
```

I found the minimum value in the array as below

var result = Math.min.apply(null, idArray );

I got result as 98.4

Is there a way to return actual value in the array as 98.40

Comment: that is not an array, there should be `[...]` at place of `{...}`. and because `Math.min` works on numbers `98.4` and `98.40` are same

Comment: If "98.40" is what you want, then it is not a "minimum decimal value" you are looking but a "string representing a minimum decimal value".

Answer (score 1):

If it really is an array, you can do it the old fashion way with iteration instead, and return the actual string instead of the parsed number, that way number of decimals is not important.

```js
var idArray = ["98.40", "111.46", "144.47", "180.48", "217.49", "284.50", "424.51", "571.52", "1887.53", "1960.54", "1972.55", "2118.56", "2167.57", "2467.58", "2480.59", "2488.60", "2662.61", "2671.62", "2767.63", "2982.64", "3168.65", "3263.66", "3295.67", "3369.68", "3579.69", "3592.70", "3600.71", "3605.72", "3620.73", "3646.74", "3852.75", "3857.76", "4031.77", "4489.78", "4975.79"];

var result = idArray[0];

idArray.forEach(function(x) {
    if (parseFloat(x) < result) result = x; // find smallest number as string instead
});

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

or, you could just sort the array and get the first item (I sliced it to not modify the original)

```
var result = idArray.slice().sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}).shift();
```

or, use Array.reduce

```
var result = idArray.reduce(function (a,b) {
    return parseFloat(a) < parseFloat(b) ? a : b;
});
```

Comment: Might be better to use *some* so it stops at the first match.

Comment: @RobG - It's not supposed to stop at the first match, but iterate over all them to find the lowest number.

Comment: But you get the answer from `Math.max.apply(…)` if you use *min* instead, then use *some* to find the original string in the array.

Comment: @RobG - Nope, `max` only gets the largest number, I could have just used `idArray[0]` instead as it wouldn't matter, but not sure how `some` would be helpful, could you show an example?

Comment: @adeneo using `idArray[0]` would have been better, using `Math.max` iterates over the entire array an extra, unnecessary time. With an array this small it doesn't matter but if the real data set is larger it could.

Answer (score 1):

You could code your own:

```
minInArr = function(arr) {
    var smallest = arr[0];

    for(var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i],10) < smallest){
            smallest = arr[i];   
        }
    }

    return smallest
}
```

Made this code based on this one:
[Return index of greatest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods in addition to those already here (though one is pretty similar to adeneo's). One is to copy the array, sort it, then get the `0` index value:

```
var min = idArray.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a - b})[0];
```

If you don't care about sorting the original array, drop the *.slice()* part.

Another way is to use *Math.min* to get the value, then use *some* to find it in the original array. The benefit of *some* is that it will stop at the first match:

```
var min, temp = Math.min.apply(Math, idArray);

idArray.some(function(v){ return temp == v? min = v : false});

console.log(min);
```

There are pros and cons to each, choose whatever is easiest to maintain.

Comment: Ah, now I see, I was actually thinking "how do I get indexOf to do non-strict testing, didn't occur to me that `some` could be used to do the same thing, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var roundedResult = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The trailing zero has no importance and hence it is truncated. So you have no other go other than storing it as a string.

```
var result = Math.min.apply(null, idArray);
result = (result+"").test(/\.\d\d$/) ? result : result + "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) will always coerce your answer to a number, if you coerce it back to a string you loose any trailing zeros. As others have suggested if you know you will always have a fixed number of digits after the decimal you could use [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

A better solution that doesn't rely on having a fixed number of decimal points would be to use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var result,
  idArray = ["98.40", "111.46", "144.47", "180.48", "217.49", "284.50", "424.51", "571.52", "1887.53", "1960.54", "1972.55", "2118.56", "2167.57", "2467.58", "2480.59", "2488.60", "2662.61", "2671.62", "2767.63", "2982.64", "3168.65", "3263.66", "3295.67", "3369.68", "3579.69", "3592.70", "3600.71", "3605.72", "3620.73", "3646.74", "3852.75", "3857.76", "4031.77", "4489.78", "4975.79"];

result = idArray.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
  if (+prev < +cur) {
    return prev;
  } else {
    return cur;
  }
 });

console.log(result); // "98.40"
```

A quick explanation of what this does:

- [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) iterates over the array and calls the provided function once for each item in the array.
- This code just uses the first two parameters available in the function, but there are a couple of [others available too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters). The first parameter is the value returned from the previous call (`prev`, which will be `undefined` on the first call). The second parameter will be the value of the current item in the array (`cur`).
- Before comparing the the two they are each coerced from strings to numbers using the [Unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).
- If `prev` is smaller it is returned and the next time the function runs `prev` will be the same, otherwise `cur` is returned and become the new value of `prev` on the next call. It is important to note that when the variables were coerced to compare them that just changed the values being compared in the conditional statement, it did not change the actual value stored in the variable, it remains a string.
- After the function has been called on the last item in the array the final value of `prev` is returned and stored in `result`.

You could shorten it a little using a [ternary statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
result = idArray.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
  return +prev < +cur ? prev : cur;
 });
```

If you aren't afraid to use ES6 syntax (not all [browsers currently support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#arrow_functions) it) you could make it even shorter with a [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
result = idArray.reduce((prev, cur) => +prev < +cur ? prev : cur);
```

The one potential (but unlikely) problem with this approach is that it coerces `prev` every time it makes a comparison. This adds a tiny bit of overhead to each step in the loop. If performance is a concern it would be better to get away from trying to do it with a one-liner and write a function to do it:

```
var arrayMin = function  (arr) {
  var i,
    len,
    prev, // prev and cur will hold numbers that are coerced from strings
    cur,  // once when they are first encountered
    minIndex; // keep track of the index of the smallest item rather
              // than copying a string every time we find a smaller number

  prev = +arr[0];
  minIndex = 0;
  for (i = 1, len = arr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    cur = +arr[i];
    if (cur < prev) {
      prev = cur;
      minIndex = i;
    }
  }

  return arr[minIndex];
};

var result = arrayMin(idArray);
```