# Javascript how to find largest numbers in array, and record positions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to find the most concise way to find the index of the largest number in an array. 
Example:
`var array = [0,6,7,7,7];`
The function should return [2,3,4]

Note: it is not the same as [Return index of greatest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array)
Why? There the answers return only one of the largest. e.g `var array = [0,6,7,7,7]` would return 2 or 4.

Update:
Quite a few people have marked this as a duplicate question. IT IS NOT! I explained the difference in the note above. Where is the supposed answer to what I am asking in [Return index of greatest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array)
I am also disheartened by the fact my first question was down voted almost immediately.

Update: Found another answer at [Return index of greatest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array)

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array

Comment: I have seen other people post questions without showing work, and they have many, many votes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36276622/1402846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so close to [Return index of greatest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301438/1529630).

But if you want to get all indexes, you can just iterate the array, pushing the current index to an `argmax` array when the current item is equal to `max`, the maximum number found until the moment; or update `max` and `argmax` when you find a greater item.

```
var max = -Infinity, argmax = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i)
  if(array[i] > max) max = array[i], argmax = [i];
  else if(array[i] === max) argmax.push(i);
argmax; // [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function findLargestOccurances(){
  //Sort the initial array to make it easier
  var arr = [0,6,7,7,7].sort();
  //The largest element is always at the end
  var largest = arr[arr.length-1];
  //The return array will hold positions of the largest element in the array
  var retArr = [];
  //Find occurances of the largest # in the array
  arr.forEach(function(ele,idx){
    //If the current element is the largest one, record the occurance index
    if (ele === largest)
      retArr.push(idx);
  });
  //Log the return array, open your browsers console to see the result!
  console.log(retArr);
}

findLargestOccurances();
```

This function will work for jumbled elements also! I've created a code pen here:

http://codepen.io/ShashankaNataraj/pen/WwENLb?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It will give you the required output

```html
 var array1=[0,6,7,7,7]; 
 var array2=[]; 
 var i = Math.max.apply(Math, array1);
     
     for (var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {
           
           if (array1[x] == i) {
              
                 array2.push(x);               
                 
           }
        }
    
    var z = array2.toString();
    var_dump(z);
```