# Is there anyway to check if a string "almost" contains another string?

Tags: algorithm, search, substring, approximation, fuzzywuzzy

I'm working on a project that requires me to check if string1 is almost present in string2, if yes (i.e. if it matches more than some threshold ration say delta), then I need to extract that matched segment from string2 and save it.

string1 will range from 100 to 200 characters
string2 will be of a larger length ranging anywhere between 15000 to 20000 characters.

examples which I am presently using

string1 = "MA A NA E LA OO KA A SA A BHA I YA A BA A HA U MA A DA A DA A A NGA GA I KA AA RA A PA A DDA A DA A NA A NA TA A RA A BA MA A SA U DA EE GA AA JA A SA A BHA E GA E BA A NA DA I TA U"

string2 = [string2](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2l7t)

I've used fuzzywuzzy and SequenceMatcher libraries in python, but I'm afraid I'm just able to get the threshold value using these, but not able to extract the substring from string2.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
print(fuzz.partial_ratio(string1,string2))
```

After performing a fuzzywuzzy partialratio check on the two strings, I'm getting a ratio of 89.

I need to get a (approximate) substring from string2 which should almost be the same length of string1. Meaning, I need that 89% matched location of the string in string2.

Comment: Maybe you can find [Longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) and check with the ratio?

Comment: The `fuzzywuzzy` code is open-source. It seems trivial to extend [the `partial_ratio` function](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py#L34) to output the substring corresponding to the best match (much like you'd get [the index of the max element in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array/11301464#11301464)).

Comment: @vivek_23 That would just take too much time, find all subsequences from both the strings and then compare each and everyone of them.

Comment: @Abhijith Finding LCS does not work that way. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence-dp-4/) on the algorithm.