# In JavaScript how would I create a variable to go through an array and remember not only the highest value but also the position of that value

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, assign

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){

}
```

This is how far I have understood it (not my actual code just an example) and how would I use this for loop to go through the array and then not only remember the highest value but also the position that it is in. What I want to do specifically in my code is create a point system that increases the values of different position numbers in the array, then sorts through them to find the highest value and depending on which position/variable in the array has the highest value it will do something different. apologies for the grammar.

Comment: So in short, are you trying to get the highest value and the index as well? From the example its `index 4` and the value is `5`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301438/return-index-of-greatest-value-in-an-array/11301464

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that keeps track of the index with the highest value, `max`, and update it whenever `arr[i]` is greater -

```js
function goThroughAnArrayAndRememberNotOnlyTheHighestValueButAlsoThePositionOfThatValue(arr)
{ if (arr.length == 0) return false
  let max = 0
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i] > arr[max])
      max = i
  return { highestValue: arr[max], positionOfThatValue: max }
}

const input1 =
  [ 1, 6, 4, 3, 9, 5, 8, 7 ]
  
const input2 =
  []

console.log(goThroughAnArrayAndRememberNotOnlyTheHighestValueButAlsoThePositionOfThatValue(input1))
// { highestValue: 9, positionOfThatValue: 4 }

console.log(goThroughAnArrayAndRememberNotOnlyTheHighestValueButAlsoThePositionOfThatValue(input2))
// false
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use an [array.reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var myArray = [0,1,2,12,3,4,5]
 
const f_MaxPos = arr => arr.reduce((r,c,i)=>
  {
  if (!i || c > r.max)
    {
    r.max = c 
    r.pos = i
    } 
  return r
  }, { max:undefined, pos:-1 })
 

console.log( JSON.stringify( f_MaxPos( myArray ) ) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```