# Set elements' height value to the max one in a line with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs with `display:inline-block` style. I want to set their `height` value so that it matches the one with the highest value. I also want to set height values auto. I've tried to show visually what I want to get below. Is this possible with pure CSS?

```
-----    -----    -----          -----    -----    ----- 
|   |    |   |    |   |          |   |    |   |    |   | 
-----    |   |    |   |    ==>   |   |    |   |    |   |
         -----    |   |          |   |    |   |    |   |
                  -----          -----    -----    -----
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. Try rephrasing it maybe. From what I could understand you have 3 divs and you want to set their `height` for the same value of the _tallest_ of them, using just CSS, is that it?

Comment: exactly! I'm sorry about my explanation skills :)

Comment: You could do it if you knew which one would be the tallest... otherwise it would require the container to have a size and the inner elements to be 100%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I achieve equal height divs with HTML / CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056212/how-do-i-achieve-equal-height-divs-with-html-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS you can set the inner divs to be `display: table-cell` and the outer one to be `display: table`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/C2dNu/

---

HTML:

```
<div id='out'>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='blue'></div>
    <div class='green'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red { 
    background: red;
    height: 60px;
}
.blue { 
    background: blue;
    height: 160px; 
}
.green {
    background: green;
    height: 80px; 
}
#out {
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
}

#out > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: +1 - You answered while I was still making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbZf2/). :D

Comment: Just I've tried and seen the result. But margin between div elements is ignored as I see. Is there any way to set margin between div elements with this style?

Comment: You can't use `margin` as table cells have no concept of margins. You can use `border-spacing` on the parent element to achieve a "margin" between the cells.

Comment: @HalilIbrahim you can acheive it with a border: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/C2dNu/1/

Comment: No problem @HalilIbrahim ^_^

Comment: A border is also a nice solution, but works only if the gap between the cells doesn't have to be transparent.

Comment: @insertusernamehere actually thats the problem accours right now :) is there any solution about it?

Comment: Fancy orange @insertusernamehere :-P

Comment: @insertusernamehere sorry i missed that comment, thanks for the solution.

Comment: So, is it possible to break line when number of elements reaches a specific number in the line?

Comment: @HalilIbrahim No. You have to insert a new element that acts as a `table-row`.

Answer (score -1):

With JS, it can be done with [Equalize.js](http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/). I don't know a pure CSS solution though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i wonder if it's possbile with pure css. If not i then should use this library

Comment: @Neal "Pure CSS", totally missed that. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's because, even the question ist tagged [tag:javascript] the OP is looking for a CSS only solution.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Indeed, I was following tags :)

Comment: @Arda i haven't downvoted but, it's the same when someone ask's a javascript question and everyone answers in jQuery. They are all guaranteed a downvote from me. You should only answer the question with the languages that are included in tags.

Comment: But yeah **+1** becuase the Javascript tag was removed