# Sidebars 100% height as content and content 100% height as sidebars

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

I'm building my website on Wordpress but stuck on one thing.

I want my sidebars, the left and right sidebar vertical in the same height as the content even the content inside the sidebar is shorter than the content in the midsection.

I also want the content in the midsection vertical in the same height as the content inside the sidebar if there is more content in the sidebar.

[See website](http://woon.erotiekwinkel.nu/)

[See what I mean here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lbLW.jpg)

Comment: Firstly, it's not easy. Unfortunately CSS2 doesn't support any method to do this. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056212/how-do-i-achieve-equal-height-divs-positioned-side-by-side-with-html-css

Comment: This works to for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.containerdubbel` `div`.

```
.containerdubbel {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: url(../Meerwoonruimte/images/achtergrond.png) repeat-y top left;
  width: 990px;
  min-height: 600px;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me!